# Using Guava for a sockets client library

Tags: java, sockets, guava

I am writing a small client library to help me with an Android project I am working on. So I am learning Guava now and I am a bit stuck.

The TCP server has 2 capabilities:

- Reply to direct queries
- Subscribe queries that will be replied several times in the future

So I am using a `AbstractExecutionThreadService` to listen to incoming messages. For direct queries I was thinking to use `ListenableFuture` and for the subscribe messages to use `EventBus`.

The problem is that to create `ListenableFuture`s I have to use a `ListeningExecutorService` and it is now what I want. If you see my code, the `run` loop will processes the messages and should resolve the correct `ListenableFuture` somehow.

So how I make the `test()` method return a `ListenableFuture` that will be resolved by the `run()` loop when the data arrive?

```java
public class StratumClient extends AbstractExecutionThreadService {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StratumClient.class);

    private final String host;
    private final int port;
    private Socket socket;
    private DataOutputStream toServer;
    private BufferedReader fromServer;

    public StratumClient(String host, int port) throws IOException {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.socket = createSocket();
    }

    protected Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        log.debug("Opening a socket to " + host + ":" + port);
        return new Socket(host, port);
    }

    @Override
    protected void startUp() throws Exception {
        log.debug("Creating I/O streams to socket: " + socket);
        toServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void triggerShutdown() {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Failed to close socket", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void run() throws Exception {
        String reply;
        log.debug("Start listening to server replies");
        while ((reply = fromServer.readLine()) != null) {
            log.debug("Got reply from server: " + reply);
            // TODO process and dispatch messages
        }
        log.debug("Finished listening for server replies");
    }

    public ListenableFuture<String> test(String str) throws IOException {
        toServer.writeBytes(str);

        return null; // TODO return a ListenableFuture here
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListeningExecutorService` isn't the only way to get/create a `ListenableFuture`. Have you looked at [`SettableFuture`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SettableFuture.html)? It might be helpful.